# Server caches files

Tags: laravel, apache, caching, server

I've installed my laravel project on shared hosting. Everything was fine until when server starts loading old pages and scripts after uploading changes.
I've checked and cleared browser and laravel caches every time but the problem still. Then I've deleted laravel files but the server still loads main page while it should loads main directory content.
Now after installing laravel again the server loads the directory content for main url and works fine for other laravel routs.
The most confusing issue is the when trying to refresh browser several times, it loads the actual pages for one or two times then it back to load old cached files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of cloudfare caching.So I've to develop locally then upload the final release to remote server

Comment: This is not how to solve the problem. You should be in control of your caching policy. Its not cloudflare's fault - cloudflare is doing what your code tells it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not using any caching services for page caching(actually page caching is a good feature), if yes please try invalidating the page cache.
If you are using Cloudflare, purge your cache. you can purge the cache of objects or full objects.